# Calculate the total of item quantity into item price with dynamic HTML input fields using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to calculate the total of item price multiple of item quantity using jQuery. I am using dynamic HTML input fields once I enter the amount it should calculate with quantity and give the total amount. please see the code below

My HTML Code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".add_new_field"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_another_product"); //Add button ID
    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="add_new_field"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-form-label"> Enter Product Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="pname[]" placeholder="Product Name"  tabindex="1"/></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-form-label"> No. of Pieces</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="pcount[]" placeholder="Product Inventory" tabindex="2" /></div></div><div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-form-label"> Estimated Amount</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="estamount[]" placeholder="Product Inventory" tabindex="2" /></div><p>Amount: <span id="Amount"></span></p></div><a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></div></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

$('#EstmTotal').blur(function() {

  $('.add_new_field').each(function() {
    $(this).find('#Amount').html($('#PCount(0)', this).val() * $('#EstmTotal(0)', this).val());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add_new_field">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-form-label"> Enter Product Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pname[]" id="PName" placeholder="Product Name" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-form-label"> No. of Pieces</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pcount[]" id="PCount" placeholder="No.Of Items" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-form-label"> Estimated Amount</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estamount[]" id="EstmTotal" placeholder="Estimated Amount of Each" />
      </div>
      <p>Amount: <span id="Amount"></span></p>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="col-md-1 removebtn"><a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></div>-->

  </div>
</div>

<button class="add_another_product">Add another Product <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
```

please see the image for better understanding of the question
[image]

There is always an option to discuss

Comment: Are you getting error or something unexpected output?

Comment: i am not getting any result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use same id for multiple elements, user `class` instead of id. See below code to get amount

```js
$(function(){
   $(document).on("blur", "div.row .col-md-3 input[name='estamount[]']", function(){
      var $row = $(this).closest('.row'); // get parent row
      var est = $(this).val(); // read estimante
      var count = $row.find('input[name="pcount[]"]').val(); // read count
      $row.find('span.Amount').html(est*count); // put product
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add_new_field"> 
            <div class="row"> 
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label class="col-form-label"> Enter Product Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pname[]" placeholder="Product Name"/>
                    </div>
                </div> 

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label class="col-form-label"> No. of Pieces</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pcount[]" placeholder="No.Of Items"/>
                    </div>
                </div> 

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label class="col-form-label"> Estimated Amount</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estamount[]" placeholder="Estimated Amount of Each"/>
                    </div>
                    <p>Amount: <span class="Amount"></span></p>
                </div> 
                <!--<div class="col-md-1 removebtn"><a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></div>-->

               </div>
            </div>

            <button class="add_another_product">Add another Product <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but it is for the first one after adding new field its not working

Comment: while adding new field follow same html structure, remove ids and follow classes. In my code i have removed id="Amount" and made it as class="Amount", for other inputs keep name same

Comment: maybe you are correct but in the second-row amount is not showing even after modification

Comment: sorry, my mistake I didn't change in jquery adding script. thanks its working great

Comment: It's a bad idea to do set event delegation on the document. Better do it on `.add_new_field` assuming `.add_new_field` is a static div.

Answer (score 2):

Full code here please try this. it will work according to your requirement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate(id){ console.log(id);
        // $('#EstmTotal').on('blur',function(){
        $(id).parents('.add_new_field').each(function() {
            var count = $(this).find("#PCount").val();
            var amount = $(this).find("#EstmTotal").val();
            $(this).find('#Amount').html(count*amount);
        });

    // });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".add_another_product").on('click',function(){
            var html = '<div class="add_new_field">';
                html += '<div class="row">'; 
                html += '<div class="col-md-4">';
                html += '<div class="form-group">';    
                html += '<label class="col-form-label"> Enter Product Name</label>';
                html += '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="pname[]" id="PName" placeholder="Product Name"/></div></div>';
                html += '<div class="col-md-4"><divclass="form-group"><label class="col-form-label"> No. of Pieces</label>';
                html += '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="pcount[]" id="PCount" placeholder="No.Of Items"/>';
                html += '</div></div>';

                html += '<div class="col-md-3">';
                html += '<div class="form-group">';    
                html += '<label class="col-form-label"> Estimated Amount</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="estamount[]" id="EstmTotal" placeholder="Estimated Amount of Each" onblur="calculate(EstmTotal)" />';
                html += '</div><p>Amount: <span id="Amount"></span></p></div>'; 
                html += '</div></div>';
            $(this).before(html);
        })
    })  
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="add_new_field"> 
            <div class="row"> 
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label class="col-form-label"> Enter Product Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pname[]" id="PName" placeholder="Product Name"/>
                    </div>
                </div> 

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label class="col-form-label"> No. of Pieces</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pcount[]" id="PCount" placeholder="No.Of Items"/>
                    </div>
                </div> 

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label class="col-form-label"> Estimated Amount</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estamount[]" id="EstmTotal" onblur="calculate(EstmTotal)" placeholder="Estimated Amount of Each"/>
                    </div>
                    <p>Amount: <span id="Amount"></span></p>
                </div> 
                <!--<div class="col-md-1 removebtn"><a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></div>-->

               </div>
            </div>

            <button class="add_another_product">Add another Product <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And I have already checked this will work for multiples rows.

Comment: It's a bad idea to do set event delegation on the document though.

Comment: why is it worng?

Comment: It's the best to do that on the smallest selection possible because of performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have made following changes in your code, where in you are finding the first element inside the array. You will get the desired results

```js
$('#EstmTotal').blur(function() {

  $('.add_new_field').each(function() {
    var elem = $($('#PCount')[0]).val();
    var elem2 = $($('#EstmTotal')[0]).val();
    $(this).find('#Amount').html(elem * elem2);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add_new_field">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-form-label"> Enter Product Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pname[]" id="PName" placeholder="Product Name" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-form-label"> No. of Pieces</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pcount[]" id="PCount" placeholder="No.Of Items" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-form-label"> Estimated Amount</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estamount[]" id="EstmTotal" placeholder="Estimated Amount of Each" />
      </div>
      <p>Amount: <span id="Amount"></span></p>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="col-md-1 removebtn"><a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></div>-->

  </div>
</div>

<button class="add_another_product">Add another Product <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#EstmTotal').blur(function(){

        $('.add_new_field').each(function() {
            $(this).find('#Amount').html($('#PCount').val()*$('#EstmTotal').val());
        });

});
```

[JsFiddle source](https://jsfiddle.net/gdnavfk9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a bit. Now it checks on the blur event of both elements and it checks if both have a value. If both have it sets the calculated value. If not the div will me emptied.

Also parsing the value to a floating point number. You can change this to integers if you prefer that. The typing checking to number will be same for integers. I round the number down to 2 decimals, mainly to get around floating point number precision issues.

Last, since i thought you will have the ability to create more rows dynamically I made the blur event delegated by your `.add_new_field` element. This assumes your
`.add_new_field` is a static element. If not change this to the closest static parent of your row. For this I also changed some id selectors to class selectors because id's need to be unique.

```js
$('.add_new_field').on('blur', '.EstmTotal, .PCount', function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').each(function() {
    var pcCount = parseFloat($(this).find('.PCount', this).val());
    var estTotal = parseFloat($(this).find('.EstmTotal', this).val());

    if (typeof pcCount === 'number' && pcCount && typeof estTotal === 'number' && estTotal) {
      var calculatedValue = pcCount * estTotal;
      calculatedValue = Math.round(calculatedValue * 100) / 100;
      $(this).find('.Amount').text(calculatedValue);
    } else {
      $(this).find('.Amount').text('');
    }
  });
});

$('.add_another_product').on('click', function(){
  $('.add_new_field').append($('.row').first().clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add_new_field">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-form-label"> Enter Product Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pname[]" placeholder="Product Name" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-form-label"> No. of Pieces</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control PCount" name="pcount[]" placeholder="No.Of Items" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-form-label"> Estimated Amount</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control EstmTotal" name="estamount[]" placeholder="Estimated Amount of Each" />
      </div>
      <p>Amount: <span class="Amount"></span></p>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="col-md-1 removebtn"><a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></div>-->

  </div>
</div>

<button class="add_another_product">Add another Product <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
```